# guzzle concurrent request, wait for finished batch before sending next

Tags: php, curl, concurrency, guzzle, guzzle6

I thought this following code would work this way:

1. a batch in the number of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` is send
2. it is waited until all of these requests are finished
3. the next batch of the above number is send
4. and so on

but in reality if I comment line 14 [`usleep(...)`] it seems the request batches are send as fast as possible generating thousands of queries to the server.
Is it possible to change it? How do I change this behavior?

```
<?php
$pool = $this->getPool();
if (false !== $pool) {
    $pool->promise()->wait();
}
private function getPool()
{
  $requests = function ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $index => $datum) {
        yield $this->patch($datum)->then(function (
                $response
            ) use ($index) {
                usleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_SECONDS *1000000);
                return [
                    'response' => $response,
                    'index'    => $index
                ];
            });
        }
    };
    return new EachPromise($requests($data), [
        'concurrency' => CONCURRENT_REQUESTS,
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use ($data) {
            // log
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use ($data) {
            // do stuff
        }
    ]);
}
private function patch($data)
{
    $request = new Request(REQUEST_TYPE_PATCH, $url, $this->getPatchHeaders());
    return $this->client->sendAsync($request);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you use the CurlMulti handler? Do you have cURL installed and enabled? It's not going to work with the StreamHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me with the same (by meaning) code.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\each_limit;

$client = new Client();

$requests = function () use ($client) {
    foreach (range(1, 15) as $index) {
        echo "Starting $index query...\n";

        yield $client->getAsync('http://google.com/')
            ->then(function ($response) use ($index) {
                echo "Request $index completed successfully.\n";

                return [
                    'response' => $response,
                    'index'    => $index
                ];
            });
    }
};

$promise = each_limit(
    $requests(),
    3
    // fulfiled
    // rejected
);

$promise->wait();
```

And the result is:

```
Starting 1 query...
Starting 2 query...
Starting 3 query...
Request 3 completed successfully.
Starting 4 query...
Request 2 completed successfully.
Starting 5 query...
Request 4 completed successfully.
Starting 6 query...
Request 1 completed successfully.
Starting 7 query...
Request 5 completed successfully.
Starting 8 query...
Request 6 completed successfully.
Starting 9 query...
Request 7 completed successfully.
Starting 10 query...
Request 8 completed successfully.
Starting 11 query...
Request 9 completed successfully.
Starting 12 query...
Request 10 completed successfully.
Starting 13 query...
Request 11 completed successfully.
Starting 14 query...
Request 12 completed successfully.
Starting 15 query...
Request 13 completed successfully.
Request 14 completed successfully.
Request 15 completed successfully.
```

So it really works. Please check your code again. Try to update to the latest version of Guzzle (I tried with 6.2.2).

Comment: It won't work with `EachPromise`. I changed that in between. Using `new Pool` instead works.

Comment: It works for me, exact the same code as in my previous message. With exact the same result. Do you use modified version? Different version of Guzzle?