# How to get execute query asynchronously and process them in correct order with Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using the Guzzle version 6, and I want to send all my request in asynchronously in parallel and do some work on the response in the same order as the queries.

For example, if I query url-1 to url-8, I want to asynchronously let the first four queries (url-1 to url-4) to be resolved in any order, and then process the url-response-body-1 to url-response-body-4 in the right ascending order. Then the next four queries (url-5 to url-8) would be resolved also asynchronously and so on...

I know that I could in any way store all the responses of my queries in memory and then work on them when all the queries are made but I want to be able a small memory footprint and low latency code.

Here the code I am using so far :

```
$url_arr = array("/home_search.php?q=criteria1","/home_search.php?q=criteria2","/home_search.php?q=criteria3","/home_search.php?q=criteria4","/home_search.php?q=criteria5","/home_search.php?q=criteria6");

$promises = (function () use ($url_arr,$client) {
  foreach ($url_arr as $uri) {
    // don't forget using generator
    yield  $client->getAsync( $uri);        
  }
})();

$eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises, [
  // how many concurrency we are use
  'concurrency' => 4,
  'fulfilled' => function (Response $response) {
     doMyWork($response->getBody());
    },
  'rejected' => function ($reason) {
    // handle promise rejected here
  }
]);
$eachPromise->promise()->wait();
```

The problem is that the function doMyWork receives the response in any order, for example, it sometimes receives the response of the second url get query before the first one.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: not sure how this apply to your case but have you tried reading the guzzle documentation. this part specifically seems to match your use case, aka resolve iteratively promises: https://github.com/guzzle/promises#promise-resolution-and-chaining-is-handled-iteratively

Comment: This does not seem to solve my problem. This would force me to execute all requests in sequence when I want to execute them asynchronously and in parallel, order them by index before using them in my doWork function, then repeat the same logic for a new group of requests until that there are no more ...

Comment: have you tried setting the concurrency parameter to 1, so it will process the promises 1 by 1 in the order. i got this from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242226/guzzle-concurrent-request-wait-for-finished-batch-before-sending-next

Comment: Yes I have gived it a try but even if all the request are launch by group, I haven't got the possibility to retrieve the result ordered... For example I receive the result of the request 2, then 3, then 4 and finally the result of the request 1... I was expecting a solution that permit me to work on the response 1,2,3,4 in this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved my problem.

Not sure if it is the best way but it work : I have set a global array of results and accumulate the results in the array at the end of each promise before calling a dequeue function in order to traverse the array in ascending order. An index flag initially at the beginning of the array of result let me know the minimal not null result to work on somewhat like in the bubble sort algo.